# Menu behaving badly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

well having posted early on and making a complete hash of it Sorry!
I have now got my fiddle right now, the problem is that i am using noJS to animate my menus but having got the menu looking how i wanted it the noJS stopped working, so i have been playing with the css and now the menus don't work properly at all, here is my fiddle [Menu behaving badly](http://jsfiddle.net/dlc1461/ac4f6qwp/4/#&togetherjs=84gS9QTJgB)

HTML:

```
<div id="header-container">
    <div id="bandmenu-container">
        <ul id="bandmenu">
            <li><a href="#">Band</a> <!-- first level -->
                <ul class="noJS">    <!-- second level -->
                    <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Members</a>
                        <ul class="noJS"> <!-- thered level -->
                            <li><a href="#">Paul Hughes</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">David Grant</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Tony Duggins</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">David Lee-Channing</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Thomas Casson</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Media</a>
                <ul class="noJS">
                    <li><a href="#">The Gallery</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Bookings</a>
                <ul class="noJS">
                    <li><a href="#">Enquires</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Current Bookings</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">FAQ's</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
        #header-container {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 164px;
    }
    /* Band Menu
    ---------------------------------------------*/
    #bandmenu-container {
        position: relative; /* IE7 */
        top: 135px;
        width: 500px;
        height: 29px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    /* Main Menu
    ---------------------------------------------*/
    #bandmenu, #bandmenu ul {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        list-style: none;
        line-height: 1.5em;
        white-space: nowrap;
        z-index: 999;
    }
    #bandmenu li {
        position: relative; /* IE7 */
        vertical-align: bottom; /* IE7 */
        /* next two lines: bar height*/
        padding-top: 2px;
        height: 26px;
        float: left;
    }
    #bandmenu a {
        color: #fff;
        padding: 0px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }  
    #bandmenu li ul {
        position: absolute;
        background: #c2c2c2;
        left: -999em;
    }
    #bandmenu ul li {
        float: none;
    }
    #bandmenu li li { 
        clear: both;
        width: auto;
        background-color: #660000;
    }
    #bandmenu ul li a {
        width: 60px;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 5 !important;
        line-height: 1.5em;
    }
    #bandmenu li li a {
        margin: 0;
    }
    #bandmenu > li:hover > a { /* highlight all menus */
        display: block;
        width: auto;
        background-color: #c2c2c2;
        color: #fff;
    }
    #bandmenu li:hover ul.noJS { /* show first nested level */
        display: block;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        left: 30px;
        top: 24px;
        border: 2px #fff solid;
        font-size: small;
    }
    #bandmenu li li:hover ul { /* show second nested level */
        display: block;
        left: 100%;
        top: 0;
        font-size: small;
    }
    #bandmenu .divider {
        padding-top: 1px;
        height: 1px;
        width: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: url('../images/divider.gif')
    }
```

Comment: You need say what problem you are facing more clearly. "menus don't work properly at all" doesn't say what problem you are facing.

Comment: How is it behaving badly? I am guessing that on hover you only want the direct submenu to show, instead of ALL submenus?

Comment: That's right Kenny but having used the edited code from Xahed i can't see the sub menus at all now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here fixed the issue of 2nd submenu display issue.

```css
#header-container {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 164px;
}
/* Band Menu
---------------------------------------------*/
 #bandmenu-container {
    position: relative;
    /* IE7 */
    top: 135px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 29px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
/* Main Menu
---------------------------------------------*/
 #bandmenu, #bandmenu ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 999;
}
#bandmenu li {
    position: relative;
    /* IE7 */
    vertical-align: bottom;
    /* IE7 */
    /* next two lines: bar height*/
    padding-top: 2px;
    height: 26px;
    float: left;
}
#bandmenu a {
    color: #000;
    padding: 0px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#bandmenu li ul {
    position: absolute;
    background: #c2c2c2;
    left: -999em;
}
#bandmenu ul li {
    float: none;
}
#bandmenu li li {
    clear: both;
    width: auto;
    background-color: #660000;
}
#bandmenu ul li a {
    width: 60px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5 !important;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
#bandmenu li li a {
    margin: 0;
}
#bandmenu > li:hover > a {
    /* highlight all menus */
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    background-color: #c2c2c2;
    color: #fff;
}
#bandmenu li:hover > ul.noJS {
    /* show first nested level */
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    left: 30px;
    top: 24px;
    border: 2px #fff solid;
    font-size: small;
}
#bandmenu li li:hover > ul {
    /* show second nested level */
    display: block;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    font-size: small;
}
#bandmenu .divider {
    padding-top: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url('../images/divider.gif')
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="header-container">
        <div id="bandmenu-container">
            <ul id="bandmenu">
                <li><a href="#">Band</a> 
                    <!-- first level -->
                    <ul class="noJS">
                        <!-- second level -->
                        <li><a href="#">History</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Members</a>

                            <ul class="noJS">
                                <!-- thered level -->
                                <li><a href="#">Paul Hughes</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">David Grant</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Tony Duggins</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">David Lee-Channing</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Thomas Casson</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Media</a>

                    <ul class="noJS">
                        <li><a href="#">The Gallery</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Videos</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Music</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Bookings</a>

                    <ul class="noJS">
                        <li><a href="#">Enquires</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Current Bookings</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">FAQ's</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Working JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zahedkamal87/h1pxp7a8/16/

Comment: This is ok here but when i run it with the rest of the code i can't see any sub menus at all and i just can't put my finger on it.

Comment: I did but was told that there to much code and i should just make a demo!

Comment: I am new to this so could tell me what i should do, Thanks

Comment: Use JSFiddle, there you'll be able to add complete codes

Comment: you can use dummy images instead of the original images. And you can also add javascript on javascripts section/window

Comment: Thank's i will do that now

Comment: Here is my fiddle, [link](http://jsfiddle.net/dlc1461/h1pxp7a8/#&togetherjs=oU2qslHy10) i have left out the header image and the slide images and back ground, hope this is ok and thanks again.

Comment: Why you used Javascript for the menu, while you've css hover effect to show the sub menus? You've choose 1 option, either css hover effect or Javascript effect. Let me know which one you want. i'll fix the issue

Comment: Hi i was using Java for the smooth slide down and up effect and css to produce the menu, but if the Java is going to be a problem then leave it out, Thanks.

Comment: updated the JSFiddle link on my answer. I removed your JS code and fixed the CSS issue you had at first time

Comment: Well it works ok on jsfiddle so i copied the css and replaced mine and it's still playing up, when i hover over the top level menu the sub menus are darting all over the place :(

Comment: did you delete the Script for the menu you had?

Comment: I have now and it's working so strange, is there a way to make the menus slide down and up smoothly?

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort i was getting right upset with it all, great.